# Proving that a convex subset of a chain is the intersection of a lower segment and an upper segment of a chain.

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

The book I am using is very naive so AC is assumed.

Call a subset $S$ of a chain $L$ a *lower segment* if: $x \in S$ and $a < x$ implies $a \in S$. An *upper segment* is defined equivalently.

Call a subset $S$ of a chain *convex* if: $a,b \in S$ and $a < x < b$ implies $x \in S$.

I need to prove that convex subsets of a chain $L$ is the intersection of a lower segment and an upper segment of $L$. For the sake of the problem let the convex set be all elements $a < x < b$ for some value of $a$ and $b$.

My (second) attempt:
Every subset of a chain $L$ with an upper bound has a least upper bound. Similarly for greatest lower bound. 
Consider a convex subset with a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound.  Call this least upper bound $u_+$ and the greatest lower bound $u_-$. The convex chain is now the intersection of the lower segment with elements less than $u_+$ and the upper segment for elements greater than $u_-$.

Am I allowed to choose the upper and lower chains like this?

The problem is number 13 from page 14 of "Set Theory and Metric Spaces" By Kaplanski.

Comment: You defined your lower segment $S_1$ in terms of some element $b$, but no element $b$ is given in the problem.

Comment: I think you mean Kaplansky not Kaplanski. I haven't looked at that book lately. It may well be that AC is assumed throughout; however, it's not needed for this problem.

Comment: @bof I meant to use the same $b$ as in the definition of convex but I have made it more explicit now.

Comment: The $a$ and $b$ in the definition of "convex" are bound variables. They could be *any* elements of $S$. The definition of "convex" is saying that, if you take *any* two elements of $S$, then all elements of $L$ between those two are also in $S$.

Comment: oh ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Assuming that $S$ is of the form $\{x:a\lt x\lt b\}$ trivializes the problem. What if $S$ is **not** of that form?

Comment: For example, what if $L$ the set of all rational numbers, and $S=\{x\in L:2\lt x^3\lt3\}$?

Comment: @bof I have modified my approach now that I understand the definition of convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ be a linearly ordered set, and let $S$ be a convex subset of $P$.

We will show that $S=U\cap L$ for some upper set $U$ and some lower set $L$ of $P$.

Set $$U=\bigcup_{x\in S}\uparrow\{x\}=\{y\in P: \exists x\in S\left(x\leq y\right)\}\\L=\bigcup_{x\in S}\downarrow\{x\}=\{y\in P: \exists x\in S\left(y\leq x\right)\}$$

I claim that $U$ and $L$ are upper and lower respectively and that $S=U\cap L$.

Let $y\in U$ and suppose $z\in P$ such that $y\leq z$. Since $y\in U$ there is an $x\in S$ such that $y\in\uparrow\{x\}$. Since $\uparrow\{x\}$ is an upper set, we have that $z\in\uparrow\{x\}\subseteq U$. Thus $U$ is upper.

Let $y\in L$ and suppose $z\in P$ such that $z\leq y$. Since $y\in L$ there is an $x\in S$ such that $y\in\downarrow\{x\}$. Since $\downarrow\{x\}$ is a lower set, we have that $z\in\downarrow\{x\}\subseteq L$. Thus $L$ is lower.

Now let $x\in S$. Then $\{x\}=\uparrow\{x\}\cap\downarrow\{x\}\subseteq U\cap L$. Thus $x\in U\cap L$. So $S\subseteq U\cap L$.

Now let $x\in U\cap L$. Then there is a $y$ and $z\in S$ such that $x\in\uparrow\{y\}$ and $x\in \downarrow\{z\}$. In particular, $y\leq x\leq z$. But since $S$ is convex, $x\in S$.

Thus $U\cap L\subseteq S$, and we have shown both inclusions.

This is going a bit beyond your question, but $S=U\cap L$ is in a sense the 'smallest possible factorization of $S$ into an upper an lower set.' More precisely, suppose $S=U'\cap L'$ where $U'$ and $L'$ are upper and lower respectively. Then using the same notation above, we have $U\subseteq U'$ and $L\subseteq L'$. This follows from the fact that $U$ and $L$ are the smallest possible upper and lower sets which contain $S$.

Comment: I didn't use that $P$ was linearly ordered anywhere. Thus in any arbitrary poset, we have that a convex subset is the intersection of an upper and lower set.

Comment: No AC was needed either.

Comment: Can you explain the notation $\bigcup_{x\in S} \uparrow \{x\}$?

Comment: Oh, sorry. $\uparrow\{x\}$ means all the elements of $P$ that are greater than (or equal to) $x$. And the union is taken over all elements of $S$. I've added another equality which might help.

Comment: @Robert Great post. I realized now that in the case of chains (with this additional special hypothesis, the $U$ and $L$ upper and lower segments are unique.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it seems that you assume that every convex subset $S$ has a *minimum* and a *maximum*. This is not always the case. Consider, for example, the open interval $(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Now, some subsets that don't have a minimum and a maximum can be described as $\{x|a<x<b\}$. The above interval for example. But this, too, is not always the case. Take for example $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}|x^2<2\}\subset\mathbb{Q}$.

So the $a$ and $b$ you refer to in your solution don't always exist. You need to work harder.

Comment: Can I assume that every convex subset has a upper/lower bound?

Comment: Of course not... You can take the whole chain as a convex subset, and the chain does not have to be bounded. On the other hand, if a convex set does not have an upper bound, then it is an upper segment.

Comment: I am perhaps missing something. How can I represent an unbounded convex subset as the intersection of a lower segment and an upper segment? Is the entire chain an upper/lower segment? In my question I asked about the convex chain of real numbers $(-\infty,\infty)$, do I find this chain by writing $$\underbrace{(-\infty,\infty)}_{\text{Lower Segment}}\cap\underbrace{(-\infty,\infty)}_{\text{Upper Segment}}$$?

Comment: Regarding the least upper bound and greatest lower bound - note that they do not always exist (check the example of subset of rationals, in the above answer).

Comment: Regarding your other question - Yes! That's right. The whole chain is an upper segment, a lower segment and a convex subset.

Comment: That makes much more sense. For the subset of rationals, can I state that the lower set described by $x^2 < 2 \vee x < 0$ exists without having to show it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15995/discussion-between-amitai-yuval-and-user162369).